# Parámetros de la función sort

Tags: python

```
for mover in tablero.m_posibles():
    trayectoria = [(mover, evalua_m(mover))]
    random.shuffle(moves)
    trayectoria.sort(key = lambda:(mover,gana),(gana))
    print ("Mueve jugador A: %0.3f ms",((time.time()-t0)*1000))
    print (trayectoria)
    tablero.m_validos(trayectoria[-1][0], jugador)
    j=jugador
```

tengo un problema en la linea del sort me marca que tengo *invalid syntax*.

Comment: Los parámetros de la lambda han de ir delante de los dos puntos y sin paréntesis, y sobra la coma que separa los parámetros del resultado retornado por la lambda. O sea,  `key=lambda mover, gana: gana`

Answer (score 0):

el problema está en la sintaxis de la función lambda. 
Cambiándolo por la siguiente linea te debería de ordenar por el segundo parámetro, si es lo que buscas.

```
trayectoria.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])
```